# Flutter Localizations with variables

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to localize my Flutter app by following the [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization).

What I'm trying to achieve is that while building widgets dynamically, I wanted to translate the data which comes from my model. This is what I've tried so far

```
List.generate(services.length, (index) {
  final Service service = services[index];
  return Material(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
    child: Text(
      AppLocalizations.of(context).{{service.title}} // Here I wanted to translate the service title
    ),
  );
}
```

How can I achieve this in Flutter? or any other possible method to translate dynamic contents.

Answer (score 9):

Dynamic translation is not supported by Flutter localization packages. You can try to integrate [google translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate) in you app. But I strongly convinced that it should be a server-side feature and Flutter client should obtain already translated messages in your models. To achieve this, for example, you can use http-headers with your device locale to tell client's language to server.

Also you need to use arguments for Intl messages according to [this guide](https://pub.dev/packages/intl#messages). Here is an example of message with String argument in `AppLocalizations`:

```
  String someLocalizedString(String argument) => Intl.message(
        'Localized part - $argument',
        name: 'someLocalizedString',
        locale: localeName,
        args: [argument],
      );
```

This string inside `.arb` file:

```
  "someLocalizedString": "Localized part - {argument}",
  "@someLocalizedString": {
    "type": "text",
    "placeholders": {
      "argument": {}
    }
  }
```

Comment: Saved me a lot of trouble, this way the argument is also translated.